# Linux radeon module initialization fails on boot

Tags: boot, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, dkms

During KMS(Kernel Mode Setting) Stage, My Laptop fails to initialize, radeon module for ATI Graphics card. The error message is

```
[drm:radeon_invalid_rreg [radeon]] *ERROR* Invalid callback to read register 0x0003
```

I can successfully boot to ubuntu, by disabling KMS using nomodeset in kernel parameters. But backlight doesn't work unless radeon module is loaded in `/sys/class/backlight/`

I have checked all configuration files which could have blacklisted the radeon kernel module from loading properly.

I have tried installed Windows 10 and 8.1. They have same brightness issues.  when I try to install respective Graphics driver, the system crashes with `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`. Which is usually caused by graphic card issues.

Twice(random cases) I have been able to boot perfectly to ubuntu with radeon module loading successfully. But both of these time the System was unable to shutdown. It was stuck at messages which I wasn't able to recover on next boot.
It was related to some graphic card daemon/process being shut(there was a timer running with it). It went for almost and hour then I forced shutdown.

Related info and Logs

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i3 'radeon'`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840]
DeviceName: AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series Graphics
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Radeon HD 7670M [103c:184a]
Kernel modules: radeon

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G] [1002:9903]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G] [103c:184a]
Kernel modules: radeon
```

The `dmesg` log while booting is [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/EKnJ0PwX)

Comment: Well, it looks very much like a hardware issue. I am not sure what answer are you expecting. You're actually lucky that at least one OS can work, i.e. with `nomodeset` workaround.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks for confirming this. I suspected this to be a case of hardware failure. I guess I have to get a new machine.